# SQL command: get min date and hour from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

SQL command: get min date and hour from table

```
TblAzmon:
Acode(pk)  |  Aname       |  Adate        |  Ahour  |  ADcode_fk
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           system         1358/05/05       08:00       2
2           graphic        1389/05/05       08:00       1
3           simulation     1392/05/06       07:30       1
4           math           1389/05/05       09:00       1
```

I want the output date and time for the manager (ADcode) to get the smallest.

Desired output: [Where ADcode_fk='1']

```
Acode   |   Adate      | Ahour
----------------------------------
2          1389/05/05   08:00
```

SQL command:

```
select Acode,Adate,Ahour from TblAzmon<br>
where Adate in (select min(Adate) from TblAzmon where ADcode_fk='1')
And Ahour in (select min(Ahour) from TblAzmon where ADcode_fk='1')
```

Output:---------->0 rows - NULL

- Tip: All columns are of type text. Apart from the column Acode.

Please write the SQL code.

Comment: Others have provided answers. The issue with your query is that you are finding the minimum date and minimum hour _separately_. There doesn't happen to be a row that has _both_ values.

Answer (score 3):

You could made it like that, using `order by` and `top`:

```
select top 1 *
from tblAzmon a
order by Adate, Ahour
```

Comment: I wouldnt use that, if i would plan to exec the query very often. If u dont, its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the earliest combination of date and hour, You can do this with `order by` and `top`:

```
select top 1 *
from tblAzmon a
order by Adate, Ahour
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL doesnt work, because u select the minHour and minDate at once, and since the min(Date) doesnt have the min(Hour) you get 0 rows back.

U need to brake them apart and select them one by one like this. With that u should be able to do it on your own =)

```
SELECT Acode,Adate,min(Ahour) 
FROM (Select Acode,min(Adate),Ahour FROM TblAzmon WHERE ADcode_fk='1') t
WHERE ADcode_fk='1'
```